# Comparing two arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

So I have two arrays, a[17] and b[12]. I want to compare the first 12 numbers of each, and if the numbers match have it print out a "0", if they dont match have it print out a "1". But it doesnt work. It should print "000001111111 " but it doesnt. Can anyone please tell me why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

int i, j;

int a[17] = {1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1};
int b[12] = {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1}; 

for(i=0;i<12;i++)
for(j=0;j<12;j++)
   if(a[i] == b[j])
      printf("1");
   else
      printf("0");


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: * Sorry, if the RESPECTIVE numbers match it should print 0. For example if a[1] and b[1] match it should print 0.

Comment: Don't forget *Apply* answers if they were helpful and solved the problem.  (you have 3 questions in your profile not applied yet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
for(i=0;i<12;i++) {
   if(a[i] == b[i]) {
      printf("1");
   } else {
      printf("0");
   }
}
```

There is no need of two loops.

You want to compare elements from arrays at same indices, so the indices `i` should be same for both arrays.